# SciPy optimization Warning in the Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, neural-network

I receive next warning using SciPy **`fmin_bfgs()`** optimization in the `NeuralNetwork`. Everything should be clear and simple, following `Backpropagation` algorithm.

1 Feed Forward training examples.
2 Calculate Error term for each Unit.
3 Accumulate gradient (for the first example, I'm skipping regularization term).

```
Starting Loss: 7.26524579601
Check gradient: 2.02493576268
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 5.741300
         Iterations: 3
         Function evaluations: 104
         Gradient evaluations: 92
Trained Loss: 5.74130012926
```

I just done the same task with MATLAB, which executed successfully with `fmin` functions for optimization, but  cannot understand, what I missed in Python implementation. As you can see, even `scipy.optimize.check_grad` returns too big value.

```
def feed_forward(x, theta1, theta2):
    hidden_dot = np.dot(add_bias(x), np.transpose(theta1))
    hidden_p = sigmoid(hidden_dot)

    p = sigmoid(np.dot(add_bias(hidden_p), np.transpose(theta2)))
    return hidden_dot, hidden_p, p


def cost(thetas, x, y, hidden, lam):
    theta1, theta2 = get_theta_from(thetas, x, y, hidden)
    _, _, p = feed_forward(x, theta1, theta2)

    # regularization = (lam / (len(x) * 2)) * (
    #     np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta1, 0, 1)))
    #     + np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta2, 0, 1))))

    complete = -1 * np.dot(np.transpose(y), np.log(p)) \
               - np.dot(np.transpose(1 - y), np.log(1 - p))
    return np.sum(complete) / len(x)  # + regularization


def vector(z):
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    return np.reshape(z, (np.shape(z)[0], 1))



def gradient(thetas, x, y, hidden, lam):
    theta1, theta2 = get_theta_from(thetas, x, y, hidden)
    hidden_dot, hidden_p, p = feed_forward(x, theta1, theta2)

    error_o = p - y
    error_h = np.multiply(np.dot(
        error_o, np.delete(theta2, 0, 1)), sigmoid_gradient(hidden_dot))

    x = add_bias(x)
    hidden_p = add_bias(hidden_p)

    theta1_grad, theta2_grad = \
        np.zeros(theta1.shape[::-1]), np.zeros(theta2.shape[::-1])
    records = y.shape[0]

    for i in range(records):
        theta1_grad = theta1_grad + np.dot(
            vector(x[i]), np.transpose(vector(error_h[i])))
        theta2_grad = theta2_grad + np.dot(
            vector(hidden_p[i]), np.transpose(vector(error_o[i])))

    theta1_grad = np.transpose(
        theta1_grad / records)  # + (lam / records * theta1)

    theta2_grad = np.transpose(
        theta2_grad / records)  # + (lam / records * theta2)

    return np.append(theta1_grad, theta2_grad)


def get_theta_shapes(x, y, hidden):
    return (hidden, x.shape[1] + 1), \
           (y.shape[1], hidden + 1)


def get_theta_from(thetas, x, y, hidden):
    t1_s, t2_s = get_theta_shapes(x, y, hidden)
    split = t1_s[0] * t1_s[1]

    theta1 = np.reshape(thetas[:split], t1_s)
    theta2 = np.reshape(thetas[split:], t2_s)
    return theta1, theta2



def train(x, y, hidden_size, lam):
    y = get_binary_y(y)

    t1_s, t2_s = get_theta_shapes(x, y, hidden_size)
    thetas = np.append(
        rand_init(t1_s[0], t1_s[1]),
        rand_init(t2_s[0], t2_s[1]))

    initial_cost = cost(thetas, x, y, hidden_size, lam)
    print("Starting Loss: " + str(initial_cost))

    check_grad1 = scipy.optimize.check_grad(
        cost, gradient, thetas, x, y, hidden_size, lam)
    print("Check gradient: " + str(check_grad1))

    trained_theta = scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(
        cost, thetas, fprime=gradient, args=(x, y, hidden_size, lam))

    print("Trained Loss: " +
          str(cost(trained_theta, x, y, hidden_size, lam)))
```

Comment: As you can see, even gradient is too large.                                                       Where difference should be below 1.-e10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, there were several issues with calculation, to resolve all warning and make `Scipy` optimize run successful and same with `Matlab` `fminc` optimization functions.  (Working `Python` examples, you can find on the [Github](https://github.com/GensaGames/Sample-ML-Workbook/blob/master/apps/NeuralNetwork-Classification-Regulized.py))

1.Update calculation cost to the correct one. Multiply element wise in cost function. Correct solution for the cost will be(with regularization term):

```
def cost(thetas, x, y, hidden, lam):
    theta1, theta2 = get_theta_from(thetas, x, y, hidden)
    _, _, p = feed_forward(x, theta1, theta2)

    regularization = (lam / (len(x) * 2)) * (
        np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta1, 0, 1)))
        + np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta2, 0, 1))))

    complete = np.nan_to_num(np.multiply((-y), np.log(
        p)) - np.multiply((1 - y), np.log(1 - p)))
    avg = np.sum(complete) / len(x)
    return avg + regularization
```

2.After performing this operation, we will receive `nan` values in Optimized `Theta` term from `Scipy` For this case, we performing  `np.nan_to_num` above. **Note!** That `Matlab` `fminc` works correct with unexpected numbers.

3.Apply correct regularization, and don't forget to remove Regularization for Bias values. Correct gradient function should looks like:

```
def gradient(thetas, x, y, hidden, lam):
    theta1, theta2 = get_theta_from(thetas, x, y, hidden)
    hidden_dot, hidden_p, p = feed_forward(x, theta1, theta2)

    error_o = p - y
    error_h = np.multiply(np.dot(
        error_o, theta2),
        sigmoid_gradient(add_bias(hidden_dot)))

    x = add_bias(x)
    error_h = np.delete(error_h, 0, 1)

    theta1_grad, theta2_grad = \
        np.zeros(theta1.shape[::-1]), np.zeros(theta2.shape[::-1])
    records = y.shape[0]

    for i in range(records):
        theta1_grad = theta1_grad + np.dot(
            vector(x[i]), np.transpose(vector(error_h[i])))
        theta2_grad = theta2_grad + np.dot(
            vector(hidden_p[i]), np.transpose(vector(error_o[i])))

    reg_theta1 = theta1.copy()
    reg_theta1[:, 0] = 0

    theta1_grad = np.transpose(
        theta1_grad / records) + ((lam / records) * reg_theta1)

    reg_theta2 = theta2.copy()
    reg_theta2[:, 0] = 0

    theta2_grad = np.transpose(
        theta2_grad / records) + ((lam / records) * reg_theta2)

    return np.append(
        theta1_grad, theta2_grad)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, why did you skip the regularization step? Have you tried running program with regularization?

Comment: I skipped regulariation, cause it will effect on cross validation and test examples. But it's should suite for train data, and executed without warning. One more point, that wrong repolarization might cause precision issue, too. So it's just for simplicity.

Comment: You can ask question in the comments. Not answer.